# JQuery QTip Modifies ASP.net Hyperlink Control's 'NavigateUrl' Property

Tags: jquery, asp.net, qtip

I am using the [QTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) JQuery plugin to show a popup dialog.  The popup dialog is loaded by querying a .aspx page using AJAX.  The .aspx page simply loads a Hyperlink control's 'NavigateUrl' property with a relative URL.

If I debug the .aspx page, I can see that the server-side code is loading the correct relative URL into the 'NavigateUrl' property, but when the href tag is presented through QTip the URL is sometimes modified (i.e. usually one directory in the URL structure has been stripped).  The modification seems to be completely random.

If I use "~/fantasy-football/nfl/free/rankings/wide-receiver.aspx", the 'nfl' portion is stripped and link is generated as: "http://site/fantasy-football/free/rankings/wide-receiver.aspx"

But if I change it slightly, it works.  For instance, "~/fantasy-football/nfl2/free/rankings/wide-receiver.aspx" is properly converted to: "http://site/fantasy-football/nfl2/free/rankings/wide-receiver.aspx".

If I do the exact same thing on the page itself (not using JQuery), the address is resolved correctly.

The JQuery

```
      // Notice the use of the each method to gain access to each element individually
  $('.supplementalRankSection img').each(function () {

    $(this).qtip(
        {
          content:
      {
        url: 'qtipsources/suppsources.aspx',
        data: { adp: $(this).parent().prev().prev().prev().attr('value'), cswr: $(this).parent().prev().prev().attr('value'), cbs: $(this).parent().prev().attr('value'), positionCode: positionCode },
        method: 'get'
      },
          position: {
            corner: {
              tooltip: 'leftMiddle',
              target: 'rightMiddle'
            }
          },
          hide: { when: 'mouseout', fixed: true },
          style: { name: 'mystyle', width: 165, height: 60, padding: 0 }
        }); /* close qtip */
  }); /* close each */
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change url to value without '~', like: '/fantasy-football/nfl2/free/rankings/wide-receiver.aspx'

Comment: Removing the '~' causes the relative link to be processed correctly, so the '~' [presented through JQuery] is definitely the culprit.  Of course, removing it also removes the site-specific portion of the URL so the link still doesn't work.